# Mouse events aren't passed to QPushButton added in QGraphicsItemGroup

Tags: c++, qt

I'm using Qt 4.8.3 (32 bit) on Windows 7 Ultimate x64.

In a constructor of a `QGraphicsScene` subclass, I have:

```
QGraphicsItemGroup *point_table = new QGraphicsItemGroup;
addItem(point_table);
```

Later in the constructor:

```
QPushButton *button = new QPushButton("Call++");
QGraphicsProxyWidget *inc_button = addWidget(button);
connect(button, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(onCallIncrease()));
```

`onCallIncrease()` gets called whenever the button is clicked. However, if I add `inc_button` to `point_table`, `onCallIncrease()` doesn't get called.

```
QPushButton *button = new QPushButton("Call++");
QGraphicsProxyWidget *inc_button = addWidget(button);
point_table->addToGroup(inc_button);
connect(button, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(onCallIncrease())); // doesn't work
```

Even if I manually set to accept left mouse button:

```
QPushButton *button = new QPushButton("Call++");
QGraphicsProxyWidget *inc_button = addWidget(button);
inc_button->setAcceptedMouseButtons(Qt::LeftButton);
point_table->setAcceptedMouseButtons(Qt::LeftButton);
point_table->addToGroup(inc_button);
connect(button, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(onCallIncrease())); // doesn't work
```

`onCallIncrease()` doesn't get called on left mouse click. Why is this happening?

Comment: I found a solution [here][1] and it works.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4742879/68304