# How to propagate mouse events to a QGraphicsItem in a QGraphicsItemGroup?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qgraphicsitemgroup

I want to catch mouse events for some `QGraphicsItem`. When the item is added directly to a `QGraphicsScene`, everything works as expected: when using option 1 below, the console prints "foo" when the user clicks within the rectangle.

However, if the item is added indirectly via a group, it does not receive events anymore (option 2 below). It seems the event chain is broken that way. I tried to set `scene` as the parent to the `QGraphicsItem` to restore the chain but it results in an error, obviously I am not doing it the right way?

What is the correct way to add a `QGraphicsItem` to a group and still receive mouse events?

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QGraphicsRectItem, QGraphicsScene, QGraphicsView, QMainWindow


class Rect(QGraphicsRectItem):
  def mousePressEvent(self, event):
    print("foo")


app = QApplication([])
window = QMainWindow()
window.setGeometry(100, 100, 400, 400)
view = QGraphicsView()
scene = QGraphicsScene()

rect = Rect(0, 0, 150, 150)

# Option 1.
# scene.addItem(rect)  # works fine, prints 'foo' when clicked
# Option 2.
group = scene.createItemGroup([rect])  # no mouse event received by rect

view.setScene(scene)
window.setCentralWidget(view)
window.show()
app.exec()
```

Comment: What would you like to achieve with the group specifically?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Events with QGraphicsItemGroup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3021441/events-with-qgraphicsitemgroup)

Comment: @ypnos setHandlesChildEvents is not available for Qt5

Comment: @ypnos Moving items together.

Comment: @user209974 I understand that you want to move all items together using the mouse, if so, in what cases do you want to use the mousePressEvent of the items and for what?

Comment: @eyllanesc For doing stuff probably not relevant to a minimal, complete and reproducible example.

Comment: mmm, what I suspect is that you have an XY problem ..., and I was thinking of proposing an answer without using QGraphicsItemGroup but I don't know if that will work for you since it could cancel other things

Comment: I will be more precise, when you want to move several items together it is normal to use the mouse + rubberband to select those items, and then at that time you can add the items to the group, then move them and before a certain action could be removed the items of the group, that is to say limit the action of the group only when necessary and thus the item will not be affected by the side effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the only objective of the use of QGraphicsItemGroup is to enable the movement of a group of items then the procedure is to select the items, add them to the group, move the items and before any action remove the items from the group. Thus, it will not be necessary for the items to permanently belong to the group but only when necessary avoiding side effects such as the non-transmission of events.

Comment: Indeed the transformation applied to the group remains even after the group is destroyed. Thanks.